# Mysterious Raspberry 4B boot issue - all official tips followed

Tags: boot

I have a weird problem with my Raspberry Pi Model 4B.

- When I put USB-C power to it, the red LED is solid on and the green LED at the exact moment of putting power to the Pi flashes very briefly but after that never powers on again.
- I get no HDMI output. Also removing the SD card does not change the light status of the green led - no flashing as it should do when the problem was SD card related.
- Also, I have always used the official Raspberry Pi Imager to either write the recovery for the Bootloader or the normal Image.
- I also tried different SD cards (one 128 GB and one 32 GB) and both don't change anything.
- I already have tried to recover Bootloader and fix EEPROM using the official guide - that didn't work.
- After that I assumed that the Pi is fried and dead - only to be surprised that I still get the perfect 3.3 V output of the 3V3 pins and also the Pi warms up.
- I have powered the 4B using the GPIO-pins however I have put in an expansion board that has a voltage protection circuit and also should make sure to not have peaks, etc. - I have a very constant 5.1 V always at the pins, no up-or-downs.
- I have analyzed the voltage for hours with lab equipment to be sure.

Has anyone experienced something like that, or know for sure I can put this Pi in the trash?

Comment: Some standards breaking USB C power supplies supply more than 5V (they should only provide more than 5V upon successful negotiation),  Perhaps you have used a bad power supply.

Comment: I used battery pack since the RP is mounted on a robotic vehicle. I did measure with lab equipment again and for some picoseconds there are peaks in voltage going up to 5.36V or down to 4.1V - would that be severe enough? I'm aware it can affect the RP performance but i'm trying to reconstruct why this Pi is - for how it seems to me - broken

Comment: *"no flashing as it should do when the problem was sd-card related"* -> You misunderstand something.  The led **may** flash a pattern for certain specific problems with the content of the boot partition.  However, if there is no boot partition found, the card is unreadable, etc., etc., there is no pattern flashed.  Just a brief flash, or no flash at all, is what it will do with no SD card in -- which is exactly the same thing it will do if the card  is not formatted properly and cannot be used.

Comment: Interesting - however for the Raspberry Pi 4B because of EEPROM on the official site it does say that i will flash four times if no sd-card is inserted. If not then the bootloader might be corrupted